# How to get password for Azure service principal after creating time?

Tags: azure

I need to know Azure Service Principal password after creating time

I searched on internet but I didnt find any solution

Is this possible? The only way is to reset password?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot recover client secrets / password credentials.
They are only shown once after creation.

You need to create a new secret and delete the old one.